# How to get row data by clicking a image button in a row in an ASP.NET gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView in a ASP.NET web application, in which I have added image button in each row:

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:ImageButton ID="edit" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("EmpID") %>' CommandName="edituser" ImageUrl="image/images.jpg" 
       ToolTip="Edit User Details"> </asp:ImageButton>
      </ItemTemplate> 
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Now how I can get the row data from gridview simply by clicking an edit image button in a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the CommandArgument with this one:

```
CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>
```

Then:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, 
  GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "edituser") /*if you need this
  {
    // Retrieve the row index stored in the 
    // CommandArgument property.
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

    // Retrieve the row that contains the buttonfrom the Rows collection.
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];

    // Add code here now you have the specific row data
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind all the columns in the label control respectively, and you can get value using findcontrol method at GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged event

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        Label _lblText = (Label)this.GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("UR_Desired_Label_ID");

        this.TextBox3.Text = _lblText.Text ;

    }
```

Comment: Getting error after using your code 
-Error Message:"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"